# for loop and array to get image

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop

Instructions are to Create an array and store the file names into a 4 element long array.
Create 4  tags with blank src attributes, their id attributes should be labeled as "image1" through "image4"
Create a for loop which will change the src attributes of each img element to the 4 files from the zip.

```
<body>

    <img id="image1" src="" alt="">
    <img id="image2" src="" alt="">
    <img id="image3" src="" alt="">
    <img id="image4" src="" alt="">

<script>


    myArr = [ "images/bugeyes.png", "images/chubby.png", "images/dawww.png", "images/twocats1image.png"];

    myArr[myArr.length] = 4

    for(i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++)
    {
    document.getElementById("image[i]").src = myArr[i].src;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Presumably there is no an element with `id="image[i]"`

Comment: Is this your homework or something?  zerkms just answered your question.

Comment: [Concatenate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition) to combine a string and variable: `"image" + i`

Comment: @zerkms so would i make a <div id> for it?

Comment: @MichaelChaney yes, I'm trying to figure out what's not working.

Comment: Why did you do `myArr[myArr.length] = 4`? That makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop starts at 0 and ends at 3, while your images start at 1 and ends at 4.
If you start the loop at 1 and count up until the end of the length of the array, it'll give the proper image the proper source.

```
myArr = [ "images/bugeyes.png", "images/chubby.png", "images/dawww.png", "images/twocats1image.png"];

for(i = 1; i <= myArr.length; i++)
{
    var currentImg = "image" + i;
    document.getElementById(currentImg).src = myArr[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("image[i]").src = myArr[i].src;
```

should be

```
document.getElementById("image" + i).src = myArr[i].src;
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach, a little different to your current technique:

```
var imgElements = document.querySelectorAll('body > img[id^="image"]'),
    sources = [ "images/bugeyes.png", "images/chubby.png", "images/dawww.png", "images/twocats1image.png"];

[].forEach.call(imgElements, function (img, index) {
    img.src = sources[index];
});
```

The problem you faces is, as noted, the `getElementById('image[i]')`, this looked for an element with the literal `id` of `image[i]`, rather than the `id` of `'image' + i` (`'image1'`,`'image2'`, etc); because you enclosed the index in the string, rather than concatenated the string 'image' with the number represented by the `i` variable.

References:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).